# How can I upload lot/serial # allocations in Purchase Receipt popup?

Tags: acumatica

I would like to upload a spreadsheet of lot/serial #'s into the Allocation popup on the Purchase Receipts screen. It's not uncommon for my company to receive 1,000+ serial #'s in an order and entering them one-at-a-time via this popup is too cumbersome. (My serial numbers aren't sequential, so I can't use the Generate tool.)

[image]

I've found a related post here, but I'm unable make the source work.

[How to include a dialog for file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40364461/how-to-include-a-dialog-for-file-upload)

```
... begin snippet ...
byte[] filedata = info.BinData;
using (NVExcelReader reader = new NVExcelReader())
{
    Dictionary<UInt32, string[]> data = reader.loadWorksheet(filedata);
    foreach (string[] textArray in data.Values)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
...
```

The code references a class called `NVExcelReader()`. Where does this class originate from? Is this part of stock Acumatica? I've been unable to find this class in the source. I'm using Acumatica 2017 R2. Is it possible this class was renamed or moved in newer versions?

Can someone point me in the right direction or explain how I might go about recreating the functionality of `NVExcelReader()` in Acumatica?

Answer (score 1):

NVExcelReader is not an Acumatica class, the main idea here is to use any existing class to read the excel file.

**So what you really need to do:**

declare PXUploadDialog element in your aspx file

```
 <px:PXUploadDialog ID="ImportPanel" runat="server" Key="NewRevisionPanel" Height="120px" Style="position: static" Width="560px"
                Caption="Import XML File (*.xml)" AutoSaveFile="false" RenderCheckIn="false" SessionKey="ImportStatementProtoFile" />
```

add a button delegate

```
public PXSelect<PO.POReceipt> NewRevisionPanel;

public PXAction<PO.POReceipt> ImportAllocations;
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Import Allocations", 
    MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Update,
    MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Update, 
    Enabled = true)]
[PXButton()]
public virtual void importAllocations()
{

}
```

Get selected file data using PXInfo class

```
const string PanelSessionKey = "ImportStatementProtoFile";
PX.SM.FileInfo info = PX.Common.PXContext
    .SessionTyped<PXSessionStatePXData>()
    .FileInfo[PanelSessionKey] as PX.SM.FileInfo;
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove(PanelSessionKey);

if (info != null)
{
    // here is your file data in bytes
    byte[] filedata = info.BinData;
```

read your excel file in bytes using any existing library. Note this step is not related to Acumatica. You can find helpful information [here](https://www.csharp-console-examples.com/general/reading-excel-file-in-c-console-application/) and [here](https://codealoc.wordpress.com/2012/04/19/reading-an-excel-xlsx-file-from-c/) for example

then set values from the file to Acumatica entity (POReceiptLineSplit for example)

```
Base.splits.Insert(new PO.POReceiptLineSplit()
{
    InventoryID = Base.transactions.Current.InventoryID,
    LocationID = Base.transactions.Current.LocationID,
    LotSerialNbr = valueFromExcelFile1,
    Qty = valueFromExcelFile2
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Evgeny. I will try this and report back.

Answer (score 0):

NVExcelReader is not part of Acumatica framework. I say this because neither resharper was able to find NVExcelReader in Acumatica dlls nor search of string in Acumatica directory was able to find any file that contained NVExcelReader string value. Also Google search for NVExcelReader class doesn't give any good results beside referencing your thread on stackoverflow. In order to recreate NVExcelReader in Acumatica you can consider usage of some third party library which can read from excel files. There are plenty of options starting from COM interfaces, OLE DB for excel and Aspose library for parsing xml files.